# network access via open file dialog

Tags: 10.04, networking

Hallo all,

i'm trying to use easytag to tag my music collection that is shared on a NAS in my home network. But my problem is, that i cannot access the NAS in the open file dialog (can only access everything on my computer but nothing in the network).

I had this problem for several times. In some applications, the open-file-dialog supports network storages and in other applications not. Is this normal?

Is there a possibility, how i'm able to access the network device in those programms?

greetings

Comment: I don't have a solution, but "Is this normal?": Yes this is normal, the developers have to make an effort to support network file systems, therefore they have the option to disable it when they program their file-chooser dialogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access your NAS file system by first mounting it, don't worry, this isn't complex. It just involved navigating to the file system first. Go to your network in `Places > Network`:

[image]

Now you'll get a window showing computers on your network. Visit the computer and the share you want to browse files for:

[image]

You'll see it appears on the desktop when you browse to it. Next when you go into your save dialog box, just make sure to select the network file system on the left:

[image]

Assuming you have read/write permissions, you should be able to save. If your system doesn't work like this, then please give us a screenshot.

Comment: hello, i've accessed the nas directly with smb://192.168.2.222 in nautilus and it gets added automaticly(=mounted?). As you can see on the screenshot it works in nautilus, but unfortunately not in easytag. http://i.imgur.com/EVEHe.png

Comment: You need to report this as a bug in easytag, they have to add a feature to show gio connections to their file browsing. For you, you may want to consider mounting your samba share using fstab. Do a google search to find out how.

Comment: something like: sudo mount //192.168.2.222/public /mnt -o username="XXX"