# open file on network using bookmark for Keepass2

Tags: networking, mount, keepass

On my network I have a file named : sftp://bernard@myserver.nl/home/bernard/shared/keepass2/algemeen.kdbx I want to use this file with Keepass2

In Nautilus I have mounted the directory successful and bookmarked it using the name : shared. The above filename I retrieved using Nautilus properties for path and filename.

If, within Keepass2, I try to open a file using network, the network directory is empty, although the network path is mounted and visible in Nautilus.

When opening Keepass2 I can no see the bookmarked entries, which is a pity. Is it possible to use Nautilus mounted files? [network access via open file dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22918/network-access-via-open-file-dialog) shows it would work, but not for me.

So I used the Keepass2 function "open url" but without success. Keepass2 give me the message error : An error occurred performing a WebClient request."
Because Keepass2 seems not to support sftp I tried again using : ftp://bernard@myserver.nl/home/bernard/shared/keepass2/algemeen.kdbx

Now I get the message : "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
But no application is using this file.
I use Ubuntu version  14.04 and Keepass2 version 2.23
On older versions I could successful use a URL to open a file.

I tried to go to Nautilus, click right mouse click, and "open with Keepass". When done so I get again the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." So it seems the network file can be found.

It there a way to use the Keepass2 file on the network?

Then I tried once more, and now successful. The filename was altered to :
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=myserver.nl,user=bernard/home/bernard/shared/keepass2/algemeen.kdbx

No idea what happened, no idea why the user has the name of the file, but it works.

Comment: did anyone got an answer for that question 3 years after?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04
In my experience [KeePass2](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/17d1bd26/) isn't a good keepass client for Ubuntu. Instead go for [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) which also has a nice plugin for the browser and a couple of android apps.

**What works for me** is saving my "vault.kdbx" file in a cloud storage. To access my vault on my mobile devices I use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) to sync the file 2-way each 15 minutes (you can choose the time yourself)

**Another solution** is using an ftp-synchroniser to sync the "vault.kdbx" to your file system. This way KeePassXC (or KeePass2) kan open a file that resides in a "not-mounted-folder"